# Magento : Attribute Returns NULL or NO

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, magento-1, product-attribute

I am trying to get attribute text, but it only works for simple products.

This is what I am doing:

```
<?php 

    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
                        ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');

    foreach($products as $product){
        $attr = 'attribute_name';
        var_dump( $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr)->getFrontend()->getValue($product) ); // returns NULL or 'no' 
    }
 ?>
```

It returns NULL or 'no'. Which is, I think, weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it returns "No" that means that there is no value added for that attribute for a product. Most probably it is because the attribute is not assigned for a particular product type.
Make sure that your attribute with id `attribute_name` is **Applied to** to configurable products.
If it is available for Configurable Products then the issue is because you have not added `addAttributeToSelect` in your collection.

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("attribute_name")
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
    ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
```

Try with this code. If it still shows "No" then there is no value added in that product for your attribute.

Comment: Thanks! In production code, there will be another foreach loop that loops trough a set of predefined attributes... Is there a way to do this differently than directly getting an attribute with all the products?

Comment: You can use addAttributeToSelect("*") to get all product attributes and then you can get value of any attribute.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i want to get products info, my code : https://justpaste.it/4yyqf and my output : https://snag.gy/y7iZav.jpg  can you pls help me to solve the error?